# How to take storage permission in Android 11

Tags: java, android

My Topic,
i am trying to take storage permission in android, my permission code works in below andoid 11 ,
but problem is when i try to take storage permission in android 11 then code not works , so please help me..

**This is my code:-**

This is my **AndroidManifest.xml** Code

> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

This is my **JavaCode** Code

```
@Override 
 protected void onActivityResult(int _requestCode, int _resultCode, Intent _data) { 
  super.onActivityResult(_requestCode, _resultCode, _data); 
  if (_resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
              if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class); 
        startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    _takePermission();
                }
          }
  } 
  switch (_requestCode) { 
    
   default: 
   break; 
  } 
 }


public boolean _isPermissionGranted() { 
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
   
       return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
  } else  {
   
       int readexternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
       return  readexternalStoragePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
  } 
 }



public void _takePermission() { 
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
       try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            startActivityForResult(intent,100);
        } catch (Exception exception){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(intent,100);
        }
  } else {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},101);
  } 
 } 
  
  
  @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
      super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      if (grantResults.length > 0){
           if (requestCode == 101){
                boolean readExternalStorage = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (readExternalStorage){
                     Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class); 
     startActivity(i);
                 } else {
                     _takePermission();
                 }
            }
       }
```

Above is the complete code, please check and tell me what my mistake is, and what is the correct bridge.

Thanks for watching..

Comment: Requesting read and write permission did not change for Android 11. So i will not look at your code as old code (working for 6+) should do it. Please tell what not works for you on Android 11+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" will not affect if your app targetSdk > 30 (Android 11 and above).

1. Must add this to manifest:
2. Request to permission:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

3. Check whether app can access storage:

```
if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager())
```

4. Request to access "All files and media" access:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" will not affect if your app targetSdk > 30` Sorry, not true. It is needed for an Android 10 device. And has no effect for other devices. Thats all.